# Send Fax via SBS 2003 Exchange from Linux/PHP

Tags: php, exchange-server, fax, outlook-web-app

We have SBS 2003 set up to allow us to send faxes out via a Windows Printer. I have also successfully integrated PHP on our Linux Server w/ Exchange through OWA/WebDav -- allowing us to crawl email folders, send out email, etc. through the exchange server.

What I'm trying to do is to email out from PHP using the Exchange 2003 service. I don't care how I accomplish it, I just have to be able to accomplish it from PHP -- calling an outside program is fine.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I've scoured the Internet, but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this question, I've determined that the answer (as near as I can tell), is "it's not possible".

If you're running PHP on a Windows server, you might look into using the Windows COM interface and the Windows SDK to hook into Outlook. I don't know if it's possible that way, but if it is possible (only on a Windows server), that would be the way to do it.